# How to find Img Src property value for Insight Objects in UFT for descriptive programming?

Tags: automated-testing, qtp, uft

How can I find out the path where Insight object images are saved in the hard drive ? I need this value to update img src property for Descriptive programming in InsightObject("ImgSrc:=").I checked in Test folder under Snapshots but it has .rar files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All images recorded with Insight Recording are stored in Local (`...\[TestName]\[ActionName]\ObjectRepository.bdb`) or Shared (`[WhereverYouPlaceIt]\Repository1.tsr`) repository. It is a single file and you can not extract path to an image from it. You can only edit it with Object Repository Manager.

[image]

Still if you need to use Descriptive Programming you can define new object as you said in pure DP style:

```
Set customInsightObject = InsightObject("ImgSrc:=C:\pictureOfObject.jpg")
customInsightObject.Click
```